# Do the Hurwitz quaternions form a cyclic group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quaternions

I am investigating applications of the Hurwitz quaternions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_quaternion
$$H_u = \left\{a+bi+cj+dk\mid (a,b,c,d) \in\mathbb{Z}\mbox{ or }(a,b,c,d) \in\mathbb{Z}+\frac{1}{2}\right\}$$

> As an additive group, H is free abelian with generators $\dfrac{1 + i + j + k}{2}, i, j, k$

I'm trying to define modulo and square root for the Hurwitz quaternions, so I can express a large Hurwitz prime as a congruence of two smaller integers: $p \equiv 3  \text{ mod } 4$ where p is a Hurwitz prime, similar to the Rabin cryptosystem

One way I know of doing this is by knowing that $H$ forms a cyclic group. I am not sure how to determine that or prove it, as my math knowledge is limited. Any help or guidance is appreciated!

Comment: This is kind of like asking if the plane $\Bbb R^2$ is one-dimensional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this group is not cyclic as it is free abelian of rank $4$. A free abelian group is cyclic if and only if the rank is $1$, i.e.,  if it has a basis with $1$ element.

Moreover the unit group of the Hurwitz quaternions  is a split extension of the quaternion group $Q_8$ and the cyclic group $C_3$ and hence also not cyclic, see [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=2PwGCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=Hurwitz+quaternions+form+a+cyclic+group?&source=bl&ots=Qjnk89AZXm&sig=ACfU3U0YDpdiISJ_rTc_Zg9z-y2Sud3l7A&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwibj_eAi_zoAhWRDewKHd7yBXkQ6AEwBXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=Hurwitz%20quaternions%20form%20a%20cyclic%20group%3F&f=false).

Comment: Does this mean modulus and square root cannot be defined on the Hurwitz quaternions?

Comment: Sorry, I meant something like Modular arithmetic- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Comment: This can be defined in any ring (the Hurwitz quaternion do form a ring, even a division ring).

Comment: I see, thank you. I will try and prove that to myself!