# Hurwitz integers as a free $\mathbb{Z}[i]$- module

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am having trouble with this problem:

Consider the subring $$H=\bigg\{\frac{a+bi+cj+dk}{2} \Bigg| a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}, a\equiv b \equiv c\equiv d  \,\,\,\,\,(\text{mod}\,\, 2)\bigg\}$$ of the quaternions. The Gaussian Integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a subring of $H$ and is therfore a $\mathbb{Z}[i]$-module (with scalar multiplication from the left). Show it is a free $\mathbb{Z}[i]$- module and find a basis.

So basically when I attempted the problem, I basically made this argument

$proof:$ Choose $X\subset H$ to be the set $$X=\bigg\{\frac{1+i+j+k}{2}, i, j, k\bigg\}$$ Note that indeed $X$ is a subset of $H$ since $1\equiv1$ mod 2 and $0\equiv2$ mod 2. Next we prove that this is indeed a basis. Let $\alpha,\beta, \gamma$ and $\delta \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $$\alpha(\frac{1+i+j+k}{2})+\beta i + \gamma j+\delta j=\frac{a+bi+cj+k}{2}$$ After this I equate the coefficents and set up a agumented matrix and rowreduce to get what my coefficients $\alpha,\beta, \gamma$ and $\delta$ must be. Similarly I show linearly independence. However as my professor pointed out, I actually showed that this was a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis for $H$ instead of a $\mathbb{Z}[i]$- basis. So I do not know how to modify this to show it for $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Any hints or help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3638219/do-the-hurwitz-quaternions-form-a-cyclic-group/3638227#comment7476627_3638227) on Hurwitz quaternions.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you! So yeah they mention that H is a free ablein group (equivalently a free Z-module) with the same set of generator that i mentioned here. However I am not sure how I can connect it to my problem. Something I was thinking about was, since Z<Z[i], does it give it to me automatically?

Comment: @Rami2314 Knowing that it's a finitely generated free $\Bbb{Z}$-module tells you that it's finitely generated and torsion-free over $\Bbb{Z}[i]$, and since $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ is a PID, that implies that it is, in fact, free, but you still need to find (and prove that you have) a $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ basis, so that doesn't really help you.

Comment: As for a basis, you probably want something like $1$ and $(1+i+j+k)/2$. The span then contains $i$ and $(i-1+k-j)/2$ as well, and therefore contains $(2i+2k)/2=i+k$ as well. Thus $k$ is in the span. Finally, multiplying by $(-i)$, $j$ is in the span. Thus $1,i,j,k,(1+i+j+k)/2$ are all in the span of these two elements, and these generate $H$ as a $\Bbb{Z}$-module. Therefore these two elements span. Since $H$ is a rank 4 free abelian group, and $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ is a rank 2 free abelian group, the elements are forced to be independent, and therefore a basis.

Comment: @jgon Yes this works! Thank you very much!  That was the tough part for me. Finding the basis. Again Thank you very much.